# Foreign Key Binding issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi I have a list of people that also have a List of contacts.

I'm trying to link my Contact Methods so that it'll be populated with the correct `Person_Id`

Example

```
Id    Name    Method    Value      Person_Id  
1     John    Phone    7777777777    2
2     Joan    Phone    8888888888    8
3     Jack    Phone    9999999999    9
```

Currently it displays `Person_Id` as all nulls, I believe I didn't create my `ContactMethod` Class correctly. If I can get help establishing a proper foreign key. I think that's my issue.

```
// Primary Keys -------------------------------------------------------
public int Id { get; set; }

// Associations -------------------------------------------------------    
public virtual Person Person { get; set; }        

// Fields -------------------------------------------------------------
public string Name {get; set;
public string Value { get; set; }
```

I populate the information through a migration script, here's a snippet

```
var person = people.Find(x => x.ContactBase_GUID == contactBaseGuid);

contactMethods.AddRange(channels.Select(pair => new { pair, method = reader.Get<string>(pair.Key) })
                        .Where(x => x.method != null)
                        .Select(x => new ContactMethod { Value = x.method, Person = person }));
```

Working Method not utilizing foreign keys.

**ContactMethod Class**

```
// Associations -------------------------------------------------------
public int? Person_Id { get; set; }
```

**MigrationScript**

```
 var person = people.Find(x => x.ContactBase_GUID == contactBaseGuid);
 contactMethods.AddRange(channels.Select(pair => new { pair, method = reader.Get<string>(pair.Key) })
                        .Where(x => x.method != null)
                        .Select(x => new ContactMethod { Value = x.method, Person = person.Id }));
```

Comment: i think you need a `public int PersonID { get; set; }`. I'm not sure that EF will recognize the naming convension of `Person_Id`

Comment: I know that it can work within the Lambda statement I set x.PersonId = Person.Id but is there a way without doing that? I would like the association by Person entity

Comment: What are the fields of the Person class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suppose that you have a model like this:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Now,to achieve the escenario that you want, you need to configure a one-to many relationship between `Contact` and `Person`. There are two ways to do that, using [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx) or using [Fluent Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx). I'm going to use Fluent Api in this case. The easy way is override the `OnModelCreating` method of your Context to configure the relationship, for example, at this way:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    //...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Contacts)
            .WithRequired(c => c.Person)
            .Map(f => f.MapKey("Person_Id"));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm specifying a PK that is not declared in your Contact class, that is the escenario that you want. Now with this configuration, you could do this, for example:

```
Person john=new Person(){Name = "John"};

var contactList = new List<Contact>() {new Contact(){Name = "Phone",Value = "555-444-333",Person = john},
                                       new Contact() { Name = "email", Value = "john@gmail.com",Person = john}};

using (YourContext db = new YourContext())
{
   db.Contacts.AddRange(contactList);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

### Update

If you want to do the same configuration using Data Annotations, your model would be like this:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Contacts")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to use a FK related to Person in your Contact class, you could do this:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Person_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person_Id"), InverseProperty("Contacts")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This way you can use directly the Person_Id FK in your second migration script:

```
  var person = people.Find(x => x.ContactBase_GUID == contactBaseGuid);
 contactMethods.AddRange(channels.Select(pair => new { pair, method = reader.Get<string>(pair.Key) })
                        .Where(x => x.method != null)
                        .Select(x => new ContactMethod { Value = x.method, Person_Id = person.Id }));
```

Comment: Great answer bud! I'm trying to do it using Data Annotations may I ask how would I do that?

Comment: Tried the Data Annotations doesn't quite work. Hmm, I still get null values. I'll post my exact changes that I made for the DataAnnotations if you can help please.

Comment: The migration works if I set the Id without using FK. I set a breakpoint to double check if it was my migration script but it's not that either. From this Image http://snag.gy/D7yGD.jpg I can see when I hover through Person = person, person has an Id and full of information.

Comment: I don't understand what Id are you setting? Please could explain me   with more details what is the problem?

Comment: Hi Octavio, I updated with my working method that doesn't utilize foreign keys. I'm trying the DataNotation method anyways, May I ask how do I allow it to have nullable ints. The reason being the contacts don't only belong to people. They also belong to businesses, but I thought I would ask for people first. Then apply the knowledge I learned to business to show my understanding.

Comment: I thought you didn't want to use a FK related with person in your Contact class

Comment: I wanted to remove the nullable int. I wanted to be able to say Person.Contact.Value.FirstOrDefault() May I ask how do I adjust the dataNotation for nullable FKs